# Response.TransmitFile doesn't work after publishing it via IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net

The code below downloads an Excel file. It works in Visual Studio in both Debug and Release modes but it doesn't work after I publish it via IIS. It downloads the file but the size is only 1 KB (normally 230 KB)

```
string fileName = "HexSwap_PreCheck.xlsx";
System.Web.HttpResponse Response1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
Response1.Clear();
Response1.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response1.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileName.Length.ToString());
Response1.ContentType = "text/x-msexcel";
Response1.TransmitFile("C:\\ltesitecheck\\5-9-2014-4-08-12-PM-97895\\HexSwap_PreCheck.xlsx");
Response1.End();
```

Comment: And you're sure the file exists on the IIS server as it does on your local machine?  (`c:\ltesitecheck...`).

Comment: @ErikPhilips, yes it exists. Actually, I'm using the same server for development and publishing

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't fetching the file size for some reason. So I removed this line and it worked!

```
Response1.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileName.Length.ToString());
```

Comment: LOL `fileName.Length` is the length of the string (20)!

Answer (score 0):

Use length of file with FileInfo:

```
Response1.AddHeader("Content-Length", new FileInfo(fileName).Length.ToString());
```